# VS 2008 and F# Feb CTP - Can't debug

Tags: visual-studio-2008, f#

I have downloaded the VS2008 integrated shell, and the F# Feb CTP and I have the F# environment working just fine. The problem comes when I try to debug. Nothing happens at all. The output window says

> ------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

and none of my breakpoints are hit. My "program" is as simple as can be

```
#light

open System
printfn "Hello World"
Console.ReadKey(true)
```

with breakpoints on the printfn and Console lines. The things I've read seem to suggest that debugging would work with this setup, and there is a debugger folder under common7/packages with files in it. Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I'm on Win7 64 bit

Comment: Does the program run?  E.g. is the problem just with debugger/breakpoints, or does the process not even start?

Comment: It compiles and runs if i start without debugging (Ctrl+F5)

Comment: Maybe-long-shot: what does your registry have at: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\AD7Metrics\ExpressionEvaluator\{AB4F38C9-B6E6-43ba-BE3B-58080B2CCCE3}\{994B45C4-E6E9-11D2-903F-00C04FA302A1} ?  (It should have a bunch of stuff related to F# debugging.)

Comment: yes, there are a bunch of keys there. Thanks for helping

Comment: Hmmm... what happens with e.g. Ctrl-F5 and then using "Tools\Attach to process" to attach the debugger to ConsoleApplication1.exe?  Does it attach?

Comment: It says components for the 64 bit debugger are not registered. Please repair your VS 2008 remote debugger from add/remove programs, but thats not there.

Comment: Are you building x64 or AnyCPU?

Comment: That's it! I was building as AnyCPU, which it took to be 64 bit on my system. I guess there is no 64 bit debugger included. When I changed the configuration to x86 it worked. Thanks for all your help. Not that you need the rep, but if you want to write that as an answer, I'll be more than happy to accept.

Comment: @Steve, don't believe that stuff about not needing rep. It's like any addiction, the more you have, the more you need to keep feeding your habit ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why the 64-bit debugging is not working, but if you switch to an 'x86' configuration instead of 'x64' or 'AnyCPU' apparently it works for you, as per comments attached to question.  :)